# Как организовать авторизацию на основе PasswordBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Есть форма на WPF. Хочу разобраться, как сделать так чтобы при нажатии button шла проверка, введен ли в PasswordBox правильный пароль (достаточно чтобы он был один единственный) и выполнял соответственно свою функцию при true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не должны проверять значение в `PasswordBox`, он для этого не предназначен, для этого можно использовать простой `TextBox`, `PasswordBox` предназнаен для работы с паролями и не подразумевает извлечение пароля из него в обычной строке, хотя это можно сделать путем прямого обращения к свойству `Password` этого контрола, например `PasswordBox.Password`, но после этого теоретически ваш пароль может хранится где нибудь в кэше процессора и при большом желании и мастерстве его можно извлечь. При правильном подходе и архитектуре вы должны извлекать значение из `PasswordBox` в `SecureString`, более точно `PasswordBox.GetSecureString` и передавать это значение дальше, например на сервер, а уже сервер вам отвечает прошли вы аутентификацию или нет и в зависимости от этого нужно выводить уведомление пользователю.

Comment: Может я неправильно сформулировал, но мне просто нужно чтобы нажал кнопку, если пароль верный - топаем дальше. Я банально не знаю как это делать. С `TextBox` в этом плане проще

Comment: Проверьте свойство PasswordBox.Password, там значение в виде строки храниться

Comment: У меня при вводе оно даже не появляется. А вбиваю насильно:
Ошибка Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "PasswordBox.Password" требуется ссылка на объект.

Comment: У вас при добавлении на форму поля пароля ему по умолчанию присвоилось имя passwordBox. А вы в попытке получить пароль пытаетесь выпытать его у КЛАССА PasswordBox. Понятое дело что он ошибку выдаёт. Вам нужно обращаться к passwordBox.Password. 
А ещё лучше переименуйте своё поле пароля чтоб не путаться между именем контрла  и именем класса